# Travis CI running examples despite donttest

Tags: r, travis-ci, cran, roxygen2

Most likely, I am missing something straight forward. But it appears that examples wrapped in `donttest` that `R check` rightly ignores are run during the equivalent check on Travis CI.

#### Example

[Here](https://github.com/stevecondylios/rawr/blob/master/R/rawr.R#L29-L68) is some R function documentation using roxygen2:

```
#' @examples
#' \donttest{
#' library(dplyr)
#' 
#' # Write output to a temp file
#'   "https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/R-nlp-machine-learning" %>%
#'     rawr(to_file = TRUE)
#'
#' }
```

Line 3536 of logs [here](https://travis-ci.org/github/stevecondylios/rawr/builds/695772024)

> - checking examples with --run-donttest ... ERROR

Line 4193:

> Error in rawr(., to_file = T) : T used instead of TRUE

Note: the actual R error - using T instead of TRUE - is easily solved - I am just curious as to why the examples were run at all

Note: `R CMD check --as-cran` passes (0 WARNINGS, 0 NOTES, 0 ERRORS) when run locally

Comment: Now that is interesting, have you tried testing with github actions?

Comment: You might not be running locally on the same R version.  The `--run-donttest` inclusion is relatively new.

Comment: @user2554330 I suspected so. My understanding of `R CMD check --as-cran` was that it retrieved the most up to date version of the check before running it? But perhaps I am mistaken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--run-donttest` indicates the examples that a wrapped with `\donttest` are going to be checked.

I think that you need to wrap it around `\dontrun{}` instead of `\donttest{}`. \donttest{} is when the example can be run but it takes a lot of time. On the other hand, \dontrun{} is when the example is likely to return an error. Again, I am not 100% sure about this answer.

Comment: His run didn't specify `--run-donttest`, but `--as-cran` now implies that option.

Answer (score 1):

Kostas' answer (changing `\donttest` to `\dontrun`) solved for me. But I also found another solution, that is to add the following to `travis.yml`

```
env:
  global:
    - _R_CHECK_DONTTEST_EXAMPLES_=FALSE
```

This example comes from [here](https://github.com/natverse/rcatmaid/commit/f9e7603d334122c6507607c209269eba100f21da), which was linked to from an issue [here](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2216)